# Need a simple way to check if XElement exist before creating it in xml file

Tags: c#, xml

I need to check if an XElement exists in the xml file. The code below throws an exception so I don't know yet how to solve it.

```
 XDocument doc1 = XDocument.Load(@filePath);
 XElement arrivalInstructions = doc1.Descendants("arrivalInstructions").First();
 if (arrivalInstructions == null) 
  { here  I would put the code to create the XElement but it never gets here }
```

I've also tried this but didn't work either

```
 XElement xml = XElement.Load(@filePath);
 XElement configuration = xml.Element("Root");

 var xxx = configuration.Element("arrivalInstructions");
 if (xxx == null) 
  { here  I would put the code to create the XElement but it never gets here }
```

Comment: Is this C# code? if it is, tag it as C# and you'll have more chances of an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `FirstOrDefault` instead of `First`.It doesn't throw exception if there is no item, it just returns *null*.